# Emacs: same buffer, two windows, one narrowed, one not

Tags: emacs, elisp, narrowing

I find the narrow-to-region command useful, however it applies to the buffer and not to the current window.

I'd like to have one window display a narrowed version of the buffer, while the buffer is displayed widened if it occurs in any other window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try `M-x clone-indirect-buffer` or <kbd>C-x 4 c</kbd>.  For details,
see [Indirect Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html).

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I wanted. 
Meta:
Emacs gives has great coverage in terms of functionality, but punts on making good opinionated design decisions.  I.e. some aspects of this feature should be set by default.
Meta: 
I couldn't imagine discovering this functionality myself through search or reading the documentation contents -  StackOverflow is building up a mapping between user concepts and emacs concepts.

Comment: why on earth isn't this a spacemacs default!?