# Is there a way to narrow-to-region in one window, while not narrowing in another window visiting the same file?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs: same buffer, two windows, one narrowed, one not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387287/emacs-same-buffer-two-windows-one-narrowed-one-not)

I'd like to leverage the narrow-to-region function of emacs twice in the same file.  I have the file open in two windows, but when I narrow-to-region, both windows render the narrowed region.  I'd like to be able to control the narrowing independently in each region.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2387287/16240).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The concept that allows that in Emacs is the [indirect-buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html).

```
C-x 4 c
```

Which runs `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`, and narrowing in one buffer doesn't affect the other.  Read the documentation for [indirect-buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html) for more information if you need any.